# iPhone - wont let compile apps from the Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

I updated the iPhone 7 OS and now i cant submit my apps in iPhone 7 from my Xcode, constantly failing. How do i fix it?

[image]
[image]

Before updating my OSX and iPhone 7, all was working but since i updated the OSX and iPhone 7, now Xcode is failing with my stable app which was working before updates.

[image]

**EDIT:** after Xcode update, throwing new warning / build error

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The error is explicit: The iOS version of your device is not supported by the version of your XCode. Update your XCode. This happens a lot, If you have major.minor.patch, often, a change of the minor for the iOS version comes with a needed update for XCode to support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Xcode 8.3 (just download via App Store). Xcode 8.2.1 is not compatible with iOS 10.3 on your phone.